# Create transitions variable with Sass

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, codekit

Is there a way to create a variable for transitions in Sass to replicate this:

```
-webkit-transition: .2s;
-moz-transition: .2s;
-ms-transition: .2s;
-o-transition: .2s;
transition: .2s;
```

I'm just getting my feet wet with Sass and I'm using CodeKit to compile.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a [mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) which will encapsulate that:

```
@mixin transition($duration) {
    -webkit-transition: $duration;
    -moz-transition: $duration;
    -ms-transition: $duration;
    -o-transition: $duration;
    transition: $duration;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
.class { @include transition(.2s); }
```

You may also want to look at [Compass](http://compass-style.org), which includes many built-in mixins for CSS3 stuff like [transitions](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/).

Alternatively, you may want to run your CSS through [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) (after compiling your Sass to CSS).  This is a PostCSS plugin (though you can also [use it via](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#usage) Gulp, Grunt, Webpack, and many other build tools), which automatically adds (and removes) the necessary vendor prefixes, so that you only need to author unprefixed CSS.  You can configure it with which browsers you want to support, and it'll make sure any required prefixes are there.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! (I did have another comment before, but I just tried it and it works so yeah...no need)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the **transition-duration** mixin
http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/#mixin-transition-duration

```
a {
  color:red;
  @include transition-duration(.2s);
  &:hover {
    color:blue;
  }
}
```